# Picture show text on hover as "rollover"

Tags: html, css, hover, css-transitions

I want to make a "roll over text" when you hover the image container.

I did it fine, but only with position absolute, but i cant get it right with position relative.

Now the Text comes after the Image but i need the text as an small overlay to the bottom of the image

```
<div class="ce_image team block">
  <figure class="image_container">
    <img src="assets/images/c/De****-D1-6a7e730c.jpg" width="300" height="300" alt="">
          <figcaption class="caption" style="width:300px">The text i want to display on hover</figcaption> 
  </figure>
</div>
```

css: (ps: i quess my css is really bad, never made smth like this)

```
   .image_container {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 0.75em;
      border: 1px solid #b2b9c4;
      border-radius: 2px;
      background: #ffffff;
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02));
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02));
      background-image: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02));
      background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02));
      box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
    .team .image_container figcaption, .team .image_container .caption {
      width: 100% !important;
      padding: 0.42857em 0 0;
      font-size: 1.0em;
      display: none !important;
      display: fixed;
      color: #000000;
      font-weight: bold;
      position: static !important;
      text-align: center;
      top: 100px;
      z-index: 999;
      opacity: 0;
      transition: opacity 0.2s linear !important;
      left: 0px;
      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
      position: relative;
    }

.team .image_container:hover figcaption, .team .image_container:hover .caption {
  width: 100% !important;
  padding: 0.42857em 0 0;
  font-size: 1.0em;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  top: -31px;
  z-index: 999;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  position: relative;
  display: block !important;
}
```

Fiddle with css here:

https://jsfiddle.net/vm73gfhn/

Comment: You need to use position absolute here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vm73gfhn/1/

Comment: the full website is responsive, so ive no chance do make it fit on mobile/tablet view without a lot of beakpoints ?! thats sad :(

Comment: @Mike: use media queries for that.

Comment: @Andrew you should post this comment to answer and Mike should accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated some of your CSS so that the text sits at the bottom. You need position absolute rather than position relative:

```
    .image_container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.75em;
  border: 1px solid #b2b9c4;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #ffffff;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02));
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02));
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.team .image_container figcaption, .team .image_container .caption {
  display: none !important;
}

.team .image_container:hover figcaption, .team .image_container:hover .caption {
  width: 100% !important;
  padding: 0.42857em 0 0;
  font-size: 1.0em;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index: 999;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  position: absolute;
  display: block !important;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vm73gfhn/1/)

**Additional**

If you want it to work for mobile and tablets then use media queries:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp